# WPF/C# can't find valid assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assemblies, linker

I've downloaded an open source third-party assembly for use in my WPF/.NET 4/VS2010 project.  I've added a reference to the project's DLL and verified that VS2010 can see it by walking through the exposed classes in the object browser.  When I add a "using" directive to the appropriate class in my project, Intellisense offers the new assembly as a suggestion, so VS2010 is aware of it at some level.  Intellisense also generates tips for the exposed classes that I'm trying to use.
   Unfortunately, my project fails to compile because of a missing assembly reference for this assembly.  The classes are highlighted as valid, Intellisense lets me navigate to the methods, etc, but the compiler won't acknowledge them.
   In case it was a C# version mismatch, I recompiled the open source project, targeting .NET 4.  This didn't change a thing.

What am I missing?  This seems like simple developer error, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you add the exact error that the compiler is giving you, and maybe the name of the library you've downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens when the library itself depends on other libraries. When your library contains multiple DLL's, reference all the DLL's of that library in your project.